# Using linq to group by multiple properties and return an anonymous type

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How I can write the following query in linq and return the results as an anonymous object?

```
SELECT ProductId, ProductName
FROM Items
GROUP BY ProductId, ProductName
```

Comment: As ever, you should show what you've already tried, along with what research you've performed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to group here. Use distinct

```
Items.Select(i => new { i.ProductId, i.ProductName }).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clean and simple answer. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You would get the same result with

```
SELECT distinct ProductId, ProductName
FROM Items
```

So select the two columns and use `Distinct()` on the result.